# Sublime text 2 - Change side bar color

Tags: sublimetext2

What is the way to change the color of the side bar (file browser)? 
What do I need to add to my `.tmTheme` file to modify the defaults?

Using a dark theme the side bar can be too bright for my taste.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You want to go into your

```
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/Default.sublime-theme
```

(old version) or

```
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Theme-Default/Default.sublime-theme
```

(new version) and edit these things:

- `"class": "sidebar_container"`
- `"class": "sidebar_tree"`
- `"class": "sidebar_heading"`
- `"class": "sidebar_label"`

Therein you can change the RGB colors until you get what you want.

[Here is a thread that discusses this in greater detail.](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/19274-theming-of-the-sidebar/)

edit: added the correct location provided by @Michael Tunnell

edit: Sample Dark SideBar Configuration.

[image: Image with Dark SideBar]

Click to See Larger Image for Settings
[image: Click to See Larger Image for Settings]

Comment: Note you can also (now?) open the packages directory from inside sublime by clicking `Preferences > Browse Packages...`

Comment: Is this still how it's done as of Sublime Text 3? I can't believe sidebar colors are still not included with theme colors but a few recent tests just now seem to show that may still be the case ...?

Comment: Location for Windows Users `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Theme - Default`

Answer (score 6):

AGS is right but they recently changed the location of the default theme file.

As of now it is at **Packages/Theme - Default/Default.sublime-theme**

The "Packages/Default" folder contains other non-theme related files now.

Answer (score 5):

Try installing the Soda theme. The dark theme has a nice dark side bar.

https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme

Comment: I already have a custom theme that I like. I want to know what I need to add to my `.tmTheme` file to modify the defaults.

Comment: In the Soda Dark theme (`..\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Theme - Soda\Soda Dark`) there is a `sidebar-bg.png` image (also a `sidebar-bg@2x.png` image). These are referenced in the `*.sublime-theme` file.

Comment: I don't think it involves adding anything to the `.tmTheme` file as these don't seem to reference the sidebar at all.

Comment: I've installed soda-dark and the sidebar does not change.

Comment: A. Matías Quezada - My sidebar didn't immediately change after I saved the Soda Dark theme to my user settings file either. Quit Sublime Text completely and reopen - that did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

packagecontrol.io [DefaultPlus](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Theme%20-%20DefaultPlus) for quick and easy
packagecontrol.io [Seti_UX](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Seti_UX) for adapt sidebar symbols etc ideas

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Predawn theme maybe you like the look and feel of its theme https://github.com/jamiewilson/predawn

Answer (score 0):

**Sublime Text 2** Package Control ~ [Theme Soda SolarizedDark](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Theme%20-%20Soda%20SolarizedDark). This requires some editing of Preferences Settings. Looks nice with built in Solarized (Dark).tmTheme.

Sublime side bar darkens nicely now, but you may find selection of side bar items is too muted. Settings edit? For example, to make Solarized (Dark).tmTheme code pane selections more visible:

```
<dict>
<key>name</key>
<string>Solarized (dark)</string>
<key>settings</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict> [edit/insert the following key-string lines]
            <key>selection</key>
                <string>#03151C</string>
            <key>selectionBorder</key>
                <string>#99ccff</string>
            <key>inactiveSelection</key>
                <string>#0099ff30</string>
```

This code pane colors Setting slightly further mutes side bar colors on Mac. Not a PC issue, since on my PC Theme Soda SolarizedDark does not work! But the edit of selection appearance for Solarized (Dark).tmTheme makes PC sidebar slightly brighter, opposite of Mac. Buggy?

Answer (score 0):

I found that going to Preferences -> Theme brought up the command pallet for themes. when change to the Adaptive.sublime-theme the side bar changes to black.

This is also accessible through the command pallet. Press ctrl+shift+p then type 'theme' select the option 'UI: Select Theme' and again you can choose the Adaptive theme.